# IDLE won't start when not connected to domain

Tags: python, subprocess, python-idle

I am a teacher with a school laptop that has just had a new image. I installed Python 3.4 at home for all users but IDLE will only open when I am connected to the school domain. Otherwise I get:

IDLE's subprocess didn't make connection. Either IDLE can't start a subprocess or personal firewall software is blocking the connection.

I have checked the firewall and temporarily de-activated Sophos to no avail. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, it's a win7 computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see which files IDLE tries to access. Chances are that it tried to look into your home folder or you accidentally installed something on a network share.

Comment: Had a look at my personal network drive, which contains .idlerc, and it's currently not set to be available offline. I'm hoping that's the issue but will have to go into work to discover.

Thanks in anticipation!